# Location of data stored by the Google Identity Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-identity

I'm looking for the information of where data processed by the Google Identity Platform is stored physically. I've found similar info for the Firebase Authentication (us region) but nothing like this for the Google Identity Platform.

Thanks

Comment: where did you find info about Firebase Authentication location?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Identity Platform - Disaster Recovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65894656/google-identity-platform-disaster-recovery)

Answer (score -2):

[IAM keeps it's data in Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/access/iam) in your [GCP Project's default resource location](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations#default-cloud-location) (the one you've set at it's creation).

Comment: Hi @W_B, thanks for the answer. Correct me if I'm wrong, but IAM is something different than Google Identity Platform. IAM manages identity and access control for Google Cloud Platform resources, so for instance IAM can manage developers' access to the Cloud Functions. Google Identity Platform is used to manage end users, like users from mobile application/web.

Comment: Did you find out? @pmajcher