# Google Identity Platform - Disaster Recovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-cognito, google-identity

Hi and thank you for your time!

I want to use a IDaaS for my project and Google Identity Platform is one of the options I was considering. One of the considerations is the availably of the service, so I am trying to come up with a solution for disaster recovery.

I can't seem to find information to answer my question anywhere in Google's doc: is Google Identity Platform region based? And if it is, is there a way for Google Identity Platform to support multiple regions in case of an outage?

For example:
Amazon's Cognito is region based and migrating/replicating user credentials from one region to another is not supported by Amazon. It is a manual process to replicate some of the data between regions. In the event the region hosting your Cognito user pool becomes unavailable, the user will have to reset their password when authenticating to the pool in another region https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-using-import-tool.html

Just wondering if Google Identity Platform will handle this more gracefully.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is Google Identity Platform region based?

Google Identity Platform is global. Google describes this service as `planet scale`.

> is there a way for Google Identity Platform to support multiple
> regions in case of an outage?

Although Identity is global, the service is replicated to each region. Occasionally there is a region outage. For example in 2020 there was an outage. Google publishes details on service imparement. Example incident [here](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/zall/20003). Service outage list [here](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-iam).

> For example: Amazon's Cognito is region based and
> migrating/replicating user credentials from one region to another is
> not supported by Amazon. It is a manual process to replicate some of
> the data between regions.

Google manages the service. There is nothing for you to do in the event of a region outage except for waiting for Google to bring the service back online. This does not effect other regions and typically the service continues to work globally except in the impaired region.